# Spark NoClassDefFoundError: TimestampNTZType while using from_avro method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

While using the `from_avro` method: `from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro`

I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampNTZType error`

Spark version: 3.0.2

I tried to add `spark-sql.jar` but had no luck. The same error still exists. Any ideas on how to overcome this error?

Code snippet:

```
schema =  """{
            "type": "record",
            "name": "struct",
            "fields": [
              {"name":"fileno", "type":["null", "string", "int", "double", "float", "long"]},
              {"name":"recordtype", "type":["null", "string", "int", "double", "float", "long"]}""" `

from pyspark.sql.avro.functions import from_avro
df.select(from_avro(F.col("value"), schema))
```